# How many EVM in Ethereum chain?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, metamask, evm

I am really confused for now. I am working on Solidity DEV, but today, I try to think of one question, how many EVM is in the Ethereum chain?

I am not joking. I really want to know, when to create the EVM. I have read the doc https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/. But still not clear about that question. So, I mean, whether we only have one EVM in the chain or each validation node(RPC node) has one EVM or when the metamask tries to make a transaction with the RPC node, the RPC node creates an EVM and loads the target smart contract or each metamask is an EVM. I am really confused now. Please help me, if you know the sure answer. Really really thanks.

Comment: Each `node` in the blockchain is running an instance of the `Ethereum Virtual Machine` which is what can process `Solidity` code via `smart contracts`.

Comment: @JeremySavage Sir, thank you for your answer. I want to double-confirm the `node`  in your reply. Does the `node` include the light node like MetaMask wallet or another wallet like the 1inch wallet app?

Comment: No, a wallet is simply an address. See here: https://ethereum.org/en/run-a-node/

Comment: @JeremySavage Sir, I have another question about this. I try to check the `Geth` source code. When we call `ApplyTransaction (core/state_processor.go)`, it creates a new EVM. So I am confused about that. What is the difference between this `EVM` from your said node `EVM`?

Comment: `applyTransaction` does not create a new `EVM`, it has the `EVM` as an argument - `evm *vm.EVM`,

Comment: @JeremySavage Sir, this `ApplyTransaction` function call `applyTransaction` internal, https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fb75f11e87420ec25ff72f7eeeb741fa8974e87e/core/state_processor.go#L150 this is the function URL, before call `applyTransaction` it call `vm.NewEVM` for create new `evm` after that pass this `evm` to  `applyTransaction` function 

Comment: If we look at the `evm` class, it is not the actual `evm` and can only be used once: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/evm.go. The actual EVM running the code is the `EVMInterpreter` which is what runs the code. We can see this here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fb75f11e87420ec25ff72f7eeeb741fa8974e87e/core/vm/interpreter.go#L47a

Answer (score 0):

`EVM` is smart contract runtime. Each ethereum node has Ethereum software and inside the software, it is running a virtual computer. EVM is a Turing-complete machine and since it runs on different nodes and you have no access to it, it is called a "virtual machine". It is a kinda cloud computing machine. the only thing this machine can do is execute smart contracts.

[image]

Metamask is just a wallet, a middleman. It passes your requests to Ethereum blockchain.